# android content provider - design pattern for hiding inner complexity yet allowing complex queries

Tags: android, database, design-patterns

I have a question regarding best practice for implementing complex queries with content providers. As I see from the android contact content provider it is recommended to use the fields *selection*, *selectionArgs* etc to make specific requests.

I am right now in the process of shaping my first own content provider. It has quite a complex beast behind with all the joins, full text tables etc constructs of a database with normalised tables. Of course I want to hide this complexity from the user of the content provider yet I just dont know yet how to implement this. If the user specifies his request with *selection*, *selectionArgs* etc it seems the content provider has to parse these and map it too the underlying structure. Are there some tools for this parsing or will I end up writing my own *selection* string parser etc.

I am afraid this is the way to go but before implementing it I would like to hear some advice from the android professionals around about it.

Thanks a lot

martin

Comment: my particular problem right now is around having a join with a FTS table in the involved complex raw query ...

Answer (score 0):

Here comes where I am right now, at least some kind of solution I want to quickly share for inspiring expert feedback and maybe give some hint for other bloody newbies around. My basic mistake in the beginning as it seems now was not to introduce a "virtual" database like layer which the content provider offers to his users. Once this is done the complexity behind is hidden and the normal syntax of queries can be used.

So what I did is having a "virtual" database layer in the content provider contract class,

```
public class JustDharmaQuotesContract {

public class Quote {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = QuoteTable.TABLE_NAME;

    public static final String _ID = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable._ID;
    public static final String AUTHOR = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.AUTHOR;
    public static final String AUTHOR_FULL_NAME = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.AUTHOR_FULL_NAME;
    public static final String TITLE = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.TITLE;
    public static final String QUOTE = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.QUOTE;
    public static final String QUOTE_LENGTH = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.QUOTE_LENGTH;
    public static final String BLOG_POST_LINK = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.BLOG_POST_LINK;
} 

public class QuoteFTS {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = QuoteFtsTable.TABLE_NAME;

    public static final String _ID = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteFtsTable._ID;
    public static final String TITLE = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteFtsTable.TITLE;
    public static final String QUOTE = TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteFtsTable.QUOTE;
    public static final String SNIPPET = "snippet";

    public static final String AUTHOR = Quote.TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.AUTHOR;
    public static final String AUTHOR_FULL_NAME = Quote.TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.AUTHOR_FULL_NAME;
    public static final String QUOTE_LENGTH = Quote.TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.QUOTE_LENGTH;
    public static final String BLOG_POST_LINK = Quote.TABLE_NAME + "." + QuoteTable.BLOG_POST_LINK;

}

}
```

with the Quote layer basically mapping one to one to the QuoteTable of the database and the QuoteFTS layer representing the join between FTS table and the Quote table. (the snippet column for the respective fts snippet result) Here I use the the same column names as the database column names so that the projections and selections of the user fits to the database. (including the table names so that the join works well)

The user of the content provider can now do all kind of queries on this two virtual database layers provided, for example

```
Uri uri = QuoteContentProvider.FTS_URI;

switch (order) {
    case 1: {
        sortOrder = QuoteFTS.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE";
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        sortOrder = QuoteFTS.AUTHOR + ", " + QuoteFTS.TITLE
                + " COLLATE NOCASE";
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        sortOrder = QuoteFTS.QUOTE_LENGTH;
        break;
    }
}


String[] projection = new String[] { QuoteFTS._ID,
            QuoteFTS.TITLE, QuoteFTS.AUTHOR, QuoteFTS.SNIPPET}; 

String selection = titleOnly ? QuoteFTS.TITLE + " MATCH ? " : QuoteFTS.TABLE_NAME + " MATCH ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = {appendWildcard(query)};

Loader<Cursor> loader = CursorLoader(this, uri, projection,selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

It is still necessary to have proper knowledge of how to use the MATCH syntax etc to get this to work. This point makes me feel a bit uncomfortable and I would highly appreciate feedback on this.

Thanks buddies

martin